# The method onClick(View) of type new OnClickListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am trying to set OnClickListener on the button to get the checked checkboxes but I am getting this Error here how can I fix it?

> - OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
>
>   - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new 
>       OnClickListener(){})
>       -The method onClick(View) of type new OnClickListener(){} must override or implement a supertype method

my method in the MainActivity:

```
private void createRadioButton(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {

        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.setText(items.get(i) + "");
            cb.setId(i);
            ll.addView(cb);

        }
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
        btn.setText("submit");
        ll.addView(btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("I have already overridden it. ");

            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void createRadioButton(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {

    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText(items.get(i) + "");
        cb.setId(i);
        ll.addView(cb);

    }
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
    btn.setText("submit");
    ll.addView(btn);

    **btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()** {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("I have already overridden it. ");

        }
    });


}
```

just change new OnClickListener() to new View.OnClickListener()

Answer (score 2):

You do not have `View.OnClickListener` in your list of `import` statements at the top of your Java file. Add:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Comment: Just curious, how do you know it already as Op hasn't shown it anyways?

Comment: @AtulOHolic: Based on the error message. "cannot be resolved to a type" == "you are missing an `import`".